# How to get data from first table only from Pdf in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, tabula

I am using Python library `tabula` to get records from pdf and save to excel.
I want only first table to be **scraped** not other tables and thus save to excel.

My current code:

```
from tabula import convert_into
convert_into("Input.pdf", "Output.csv", pages = "all")
```

But it gets all tables. Can someone help me getting desired results.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to perform some operations before saving to the output file. To achieve this I would use `tabula.read_pdf` which will return a list of extracted data frames. You can then select which data frames you want and save them to your output file.

```
import pandas as pd
from tabula import read_pdf
dfs = read_pdf('input.pdf', pages='all')
```

Then you can merge all dataframes except the first and save to output file:

```
output_df = pd.concat(dfs[1:], axis=0)
output_df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the first table, you can try:

```
from tabula import read_pdf
dfs = read_pdf('input.pdf', pages='all')

first_table_df=df[0]
first_table_df.to_csv('output.csv')
```